# Display customer list in ReactJs using es2015 class syntax

Tags: javascript, react.js

**EDIT: Version 2 is now available [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/124125/101283)**

I am just getting to grips with ReactJs using es2015 classes, i have just converted a simple portion of an app i maintain into react code and tried a few things out, this displays a list of customers with a sub-list of the animals that they own.

Am i utilising es2015 features correctly, are there more techniques i could be using to make my code more lean, easy to read and efficient?

```
"use strict"
import {Input, Glyphicon} from 'react-bootstrap'

export class CustomerView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state  = {
            data: props.initialData,
            searchText: '',
            helpText: 'Type to search for'
        }
    }

    validationState() {
        let length = this.state.searchText.length;
        let dataLength = this.state.data.length
        console.log("DataLength: " + dataLength)
        if (dataLength == 0) return 'error'
        else if (length > 2) return 'success'
        else if (length > 0) return 'warning'
    }

    handleChange() {

        //split the search text by space delimiter
        //return customers where the name contains all values in the array
        //only search when 3 chars or more
        let allText = this.refs.input.getValue()
        this.state.searchText = allText
        let searchText = allText.toLowerCase().split(' ')

        if (allText.length > 2) {
            console.log("it changed")
            // This could also be done using ReactLink:
            // http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html
            let filteredCustomers = this.props.initialData.filter(customer =>
                                        searchText.filter(text =>
                                            customer.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) >= 0).length 
                                            == searchText.length)
            this.setState({
                data: filteredCustomers,
                helpText: 'Found ' + filteredCustomers.length + ' customers.'
            })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                data: this.props.initialData,
                helpText: 'Enter three or more characters to search'
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="customerApp">
                <h1>Customers</h1>
                <Input type="text"
                       placeholder="Enter text"
                       label="Customer search"
                       help={this.state.helpText}
                       hasFeedback
                       ref="input"
                       bsStyle={this.validationState()}
                       groupClassName="group-class"
                       labelClassName="label-class"
                       onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                <CustomerList customers={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        );   
    }
}

module.exports = CustomerView

class CustomerList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let customers = this.props.customers;
        return (
            <div className="customerList">
                {
                customers.map(function (customer, i) {
                    return (
                        <Customer name={customer.name} animals={customer.animals} key={i}></Customer>
                    );
                })
                }
            </div>  
            );
    }
}

class Customer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TogglePanel title={this.props.name}>
                <AnimalList animals={this.props.animals}></AnimalList>
                <TogglePanel title="Addresses">
                    Some stuff about addresses
                </TogglePanel>
            </TogglePanel>  
        );
    }
}

class TogglePanel extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
              <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    <h2 className="customerName panel-title">
                        <TogglePill onClick={this.toggleBody.bind(this)} ref="bodyToggle"/>
                        {this.props.title}
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body" ref="panelBody" style={{display: "none"}}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>  
        );
    }
    toggleBody() {
        let body = this.refs.panelBody
        let toggle = this.refs.bodyToggle

        if (!this.bodyHeight) {
            //get the original height of the block
            body.style.display = "block"
            this.bodyHeight = this.refs.panelBody.clientHeight + "px"
            body.style.maxHeight = "0px"
            body.style.paddingTop = "0px"
            body.style.paddingBottom = "0px"
            body.style.overflow = "hidden"

        }

        if (body.style.maxHeight == "0px") {
            this.refs.bodyToggle.open()
            body.style.maxHeight = "0px"
            body.style.display = "block"
            body.style.transition = "all 0.3s ease-in"
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                body.style.maxHeight = this.bodyHeight
                body.style.paddingTop = "15px"
                body.style.paddingBottom = "15px"
            }.bind(this));
        }
        else {
            this.refs.bodyToggle.close()
            body.transition = "all 0.3s ease-out"
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                body.style.maxHeight = "0px"
                body.style.paddingTop = "0px"
                body.style.paddingBottom = "0px"
            });
        }
    }
}

class TogglePill extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    open() { 
        this.refs.pillIcon.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" 
    }

    close() { 
        this.refs.pillIcon.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" 
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <span ref="pillIcon" 
                  onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this)} 
                  className="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"
                  style={{
                     fontSize: "0.7em",
                     marginLeft: "-10px",
                     marginRight: "10px"
                  }}>
            </span>
        );
    }
}

class AnimalList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let animals = this.props.animals;
        return (
            <div>
              <em>{animals.length} Animal{(animals.length !== 1) ? "s":""}:</em>
              <ul className="animalList">
                  {
                      animals.map(function (animal, i) {
                          return (<Animal name={animal.name} key={i}></Animal>);
                            })         
                        }
              </ul>
             </div>  
            );
    }
}

class Animal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <li className="animal">{this.props.name}</li>    
        );
    } 
}
```

CustomerView accepts initialData in the following format:

```
{"initialData":[
    {
        "name":"Mr Joe Bloggs",
        "animals":[
            {"name":"Alec"},
            {"name":"Flo"},
            {"name":"Diesel"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Mrs. Jane Bloggs",
        "animals":[
            {"name":"Maddy"},
            {"name":"Queenie"},
            {"name":"Pluto"}
        ]
    }
]}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Oops sorry @Vogel612! Is there a good basic guide to CodeReview somewhere round here? It seems to be a bit of a different concept to stack overflow, e.g. when should i accept a review as an answer?

Comment: ooh wait it looks like that link you gave covers most of those questions, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to say about this, so I won't be able to cover everything in this review.

---

### `getInitialState`

This is very bad in React:

> ```
> this.state  = {
>     data: props.initialData,
>     searchText: '',
>     helpText: 'Type to search for'
> }
> ```

Instead, you should create `getInitialState` method for this component. All this method has to do is just return the initial state in object form. So, it'd look like this:

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        data: props.initialData,
        searchText: '',
        helpText: 'Type to search for'
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

In fact, I was wrong about the state. For ES6 classes, it is okay to set state like that in the constructor. Otherwise, you should be using `getInitialState`.

---

### Stateless functional components

For every component you have that does not have some sort of state, you should turn that into a functional component - basically, it's just a plain-old function that takes in an object of props and returns the JSX output; no state involved.

One, very simple example is the `Animal` component. That could be turned into this:

```
const Animal = ({ name }) => <li className="animal">{name}</li>
```

---

### Inline styles

Inline styles are bad:

> ```
> body.style.display = "block"
> this.bodyHeight = this.refs.panelBody.clientHeight + "px"
> body.style.maxHeight = "0px"
> body.style.paddingTop = "0px"
> body.style.paddingBottom = "0px"
> body.style.overflow = "hidden"
> ```

They make code much harder to maintain. Either way, this is why we have style sheets; they help with organization, too.

You should try to refactor as much of this style setting code as possible into CSS classes that could be toggled through the JavaScript.

Comment: I was using `getInitialState()` originally, but when i changed to es2015 classes it didn't work anymore (`Cannot read property 'helpText' of null`) and i had to change and set it in the class constructor..

Comment: I got the idea to use `this.state` in the constructor from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes)

Comment: @NickDewitt Oh, then I'd go with what they say. Sorry!

Comment: No prob, there's so much conflicting documentation out there at the mo! I like the stateless example, i do plan to make `Animal` more complex though, i agree with the styles bit too i'm going to switch that out for `react-bootstrap` components anyway i think.

Comment: version 2 is available [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/124125/101283) if you have time to do me the honor :)